# Append items in generator to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, bioinformatics

I have a generator called fasta containing information from a fastA file. When I run:

```
for x, y in fasta:
    header = x
    seq = y

    print(header, seq)
```

I get the first header and then the first sequence. However, my fastA file has multiple lines of headers and sequences and I am trying to make a list with just the sequences. I tried something like this:

```
seq = list()

for x, y in fasta:
    seq.append(fasta.__next__(y))

    print(seq)
```

but I get "TypeError: expected 0 arguments, got 1".

Comment: You're not just looking for `seq.append(y)`?

Comment: what about `seqs = [seq for (header, seq) in fasta]`?

Comment: @AdamKG when I do that, only the first sequence gets put into the list for some reason.

Comment: In that case, we probably don't have enough information to answer your question. It sounds like the other sequences aren't inside fasta.

Comment: @jedwards I only want the sequences in my list, not the headers. edit. nvm that worked great thank you.

Comment: @glich they are there though, because when I do something like a = fasta, print(next(a)) multiple times, the other sequences print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
seq = [y for (x, y) in fasta]
```

Works great. Thanks @jedwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [seq for _, seq in fasta]
```